# CoreData performBackgroundTask conflict

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I am using CoreData and am having issues when I try to saveContext in the performBackgroundTask function of the container.

I am calling this from multiple places at the same time.  My understanding is that each time the thread will be different leading to issues when trying to save to the persistentStore.

I thought of using childContext's and other approaches until I came across the following article:

https://blog.five.agency/how-to-import-a-large-data-set-using-core-data-6c248a503148

In the article the coreData stack is as follows:

```
final class DataCoordinator {
    //MARK: - singleton
    static let sharedInstance = DataCoordinator()

    //MARK: - init
    public var container : NSPersistentContainer
    private init() {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Model")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (_, error) in
            if let error = error {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error)")
            }
        })
    }

    //MARK: - perform methods
    static func performBackgroundTask(_ block: @escaping (NSManagedObjectContext) -> Void) {
        DataCoordinator.sharedInstance.container.performBackgroundTask(block)
    }

    static func performViewTask(_ block: @escaping (NSManagedObjectContext) -> Void) {
        block(DataCoordinator.sharedInstance.container.viewContext)
    }
}
```

My question is using this approach, will the static func performBackgroundTask overcome this problem and always be giving me the same background context on the same queue or is this no different than what I was previously doing with container.performBackgroundTask everytime?

Wondering how I can save from multiple places at the same time on the same queue?

Comment: Not related to the issue but the singleton syntax is cumbersome and outdated. Replace `private static var coordinator: DataCoordinator?` with `static let sharedInstance = DataCoordinator()` and delete the entire `sharedInstance()` method.

Comment: thanks.  I've updated my code to remove singleton.

Comment: and edited the code to reflect your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Hi first thing is its not about queue, `NSManagedObjectContext` run on different queues, like viewContext run on main queue. So in your case I think you want to use same `NSManagedObjectContext` to save from different places ? If this is the case you can get one newBackgroundContext and save the reference of it and use this context to save your task from all the places. Use the below method of `NSPersistentContainer` to get a background context.

```
func newBackgroundContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext
```

If my understanding about your problem is wrong please let me know more so I can give you other solution.

Again the below method of the tutorial u mentioned will not work for you

```
static func performBackgroundTask(_ block: @escaping (NSManagedObjectContext) -> Void) {
        DataCoordinator.sharedInstance().container.performBackgroundTask(block)
    }
```

because `performBackgroundTask` always create a new context. Apple doc says:

Each time this method is invoked, the persistent container creates a new `NSManagedObjectContext` with the concurrencyType set to `NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.privateQueueConcurrencyType.` The persistent container then executes the passed in block against that newly created context on the context’s private queue.

Comment: I understand what your saying but I'm wondering if making it a static function will just call the performBackgroundTask function once and pass it around in the same way putting static in front of a variable will.  If so it should work with one context only.

Comment: you are saying its a static function so always work on same context ?

Comment: I'm asking if that is the case. I haven't used static functions before

Comment: Ok, even though its static func. it will  perform task on new context every time u call.